# SSIS Package External columns for component are out of synchronization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a solution in BIDS that contains many SSIS packages.
I had to restore the database that is being used by the OLEDB connection managers in my SSIS packages. Even though, all the data structure stayed the same as before when I developed those packages, all of my packages right now are getting error/warning icons stating that "external columns for component are out of synchronization" or "column cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string datatypes".

When I go into each individual task in the package that shows error/warning, all I have to do is click ok, and they would go away.

I have about 50 packages in the solution, so refreshing it like this for each package is a pain and time-consuming.

Is there a fast an easy way to get rid of those errors/warnings for all the packages at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but since you changed the back end of it, BIDS has no way to make sure that it has the correct version of Metadata. If this package was running on a scheduled job, you wouldn't have to do this IMO. 
To answer your question, there is no automatic way of doing it.